# Remove Captcha verification on firebase phone auth in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, captcha, google-play-integrity-api

I'd like to ask how to Remove Captcha Verification with Firebase Phone Auth in Android.

1. I've uploaded App signing key certificate's (SHA-1 and SHA-256) from Android Console to Firebase.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CmJo.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drN8g.png)
2. I've enabled App Integrity in Android Console and I've linked it with the right Google Cloud project.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLdcM.png)
3. I've enabled Google Play Integrity in Google Cloud Console.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjpme.png)
4. I'm using last libraries recommended into the Firebase Phone Auth doc. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).
5. I'm using a real device (Google Pixel 4a) with Google Services installed.
6. The app is available for download in Google Play store.
7. The Android project is new, so I can't enable SafetyNet because isn't available right now.

With all the previous steps, when I try to do Firebase Phone Auth, I'm getting this result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYXfV.png)

I think the Google Play Integrity verification is failing, and this is why the CAPTCHA code verification appears.

Have I forgotten any mandatory step?

Anyone is having the same problem?

Thanks in advance.